# enabling AcousticEchoCanceler.in nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript, recording

I am trying to use the AcousticEchoCanceler class from the android sdk in nativescript, I haven't figured out how can I use this class inside the TNSRecorder nativescript plugin?

AcousticEchoCanceler - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AcousticEchoCanceler

Comment: You will have to setup a AudioSource, and pass it as `source` in options param. Use the same audio source to enable AcousticEchoCanceler.

Comment: How can i create an audio source? I mean, how do I use the Android sdk to create an audio source in nativescript